# Naming and Iconing

Tags: vb.net

I've programmed a app via visual basic .Net and after made an installation file via Advanced Installer
But both my app's icon and name aren't available .
I mean after installation my app appear in desktop with "Windows Application" and no icon so 
What can I do to solve this?

Please help

Comment: Are the name and icon correct in your Debug/Release folder?

Comment: May not icon but what do you mean by being name in D/R folder?

Comment: If you go into your Project properties, the "Assembly name" will end up being the name of the .exe after it is built, and you can set the icon there as well.  You should see them in the project's folder in explorer under \bin\Debug or \bin\Release.  Wherever your .exe goes after it builds.

Comment: Thanks and just a problem is it as you said via Advanced installer?

Comment: And I'm a beginner. So can you explain what should I do to set up them (Icon , Name )

Comment: I'm talking about in Visual Studio, not Advanced Installer.  Right click on your Project name on the right side in the Solution Explorer and click on Properties.  In the Application section you can set the Assembly Name and Icon.

Comment: Advanced Installer is a installer and all problem is with Advanced Installer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the [name of your shortcut and its icon](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html#shortcuts) from Advanced Installer, as indicated in the tutorial I linked.

After this rebuild the installer and re-install it.